# Retirando elementos em comum entre 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, array, typescript, ionic3

Tenho uma lista fixa que contém 20 itens, e tenho uma outra lista que vem do banco. Preciso que os itens que tenho na minha lista fixa seja comparado com o que vem do banco e, se existirem itens iguais, que sejam apagados da lista que vem do banco.

Para melhor entendimento:

Tenho o primeiro array que vem do banco:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
var array2 = [1,2,3]
```

Ou seja, quero que o `array1` se torne:

```
array1 = [4,5,6] -- Eliminando os itens em comum com o array2.
```

Claro que com esse exemplo eu consigo fazer usando filter, porém com o objeto que vem do banco tem que comparar para dar certo e não estou conseguindo fazer essa comparação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o seu problema basta usar um `filter` combinado com um `includes` conforme o script a seguir:

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let array2 = [1,2,3]

array1 = array1.filter(item => !array2.includes(item))

console.log(array1);
```

Caso você tenha um objeto complexo, basta alterar o `includes` para `some` e verificar a propriedade que você quiser comparar, como no exemplo a seguir:

```js
let array1 = [{id:1, nome:"lalala"},{id:2, nome:"lalala"},{id:3, nome:"lalala"},{id:4, nome:"lalala"},{id:5, nome:"lalala"},{id:6, nome:"lalala"}]

let array2 = [{id:1, nome:"lalala"},{id:2, nome:"lalala"},{id:3, nome:"lalala"}]

array1 = array1.filter(item => !array2.some(item2 => item2.id === item.id))

console.log(array1)
```

Comment: Usando o some casou perfeito, muito obrigado!